# Receipt_id is null in Paypal response, How can I get it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

I have integrated Paypal with my rails application by activemerchant gem, As of now I'm getting token and payer_id, but I need receipt_id which is null in response.

I have followed steps given in this [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout).

Response of Paypal is given below

```
"timestamp"=>"2016-04-12T19:23:46Z", "ack"=>"Success", 
"correlation_id"=>"000a000f000r", "version"=>"124", "build"=>"000000", 
"token"=>"AB-000000000000000", "transaction_id"=>"kjKJKHkj09809FED2", 
"parent_transaction_id"=>NULL, "receipt_id"=>NULL, 
"transaction_type"=>"express-checkout", "payment_type"=>"instant", 
"payment_date"=>"2016-04-12T19:23:46Z", "gross_amount"=>"160.00", 
"gross_amount_currency_id"=>"USD", "fee_amount"=>"6.54", 
"fee_amount_currency_id"=>"USD", "tax_amount"=>"0.00", 
"tax_amount_currency_id"=>"USD", "exchange_rate"=>NULL, 
"payment_status"=>"Completed", "pending_reason"=>"none", 
"reason_code"=>"none", "protection_eligibility"=>"Eligible", 
"protection_eligibility_type"=>"ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible", 
"secure_merchant_account_id"=>"JHBJKJKJBKJBKJH",  
"success_page_redirect_requested"=>"false", 
"coupled_payment_info"=>NULL, "Token"=>"AB-000000000000000", 
"PaymentInfo"=>"{"TransactionID"=>"kjKJKHkj09809FED2", 
"ParentTransactionID"=>nil, "ReceiptID"=>nil, 
"TransactionType"=>"express-checkout", "PaymentType"=>"instant", 
"PaymentDate"=>"2016-04-12T19:23:46Z", "GrossAmount"=>"160.00", 
"FeeAmount"=>"6.54", "TaxAmount"=>"0.00", "ExchangeRate"=>nil, 
"PaymentStatus"=>"Completed", "PendingReason"=>"none", 
"ReasonCode"=>"none", "ProtectionEligibility"=>"Eligible", 
"ProtectionEligibilityType"=>"ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible", 
"SellerDetails"=>{"SecureMerchantAccountID"=>"JHBJKJKJBKJBKJH"}}", 
"SuccessPageRedirectRequested"=>"false", "CoupledPaymentInfo"=>NULL
```

Is there any configuration in Paypal account to get receipt_id, or any request parameter I have to add/change?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the sandbox or is this for actual transactions? I have a similar issue (in .NET actually) but using the sandbox I also have a null receipt_id, I was thinking it might possibly be because it is not a full transaction and that a real transaction might have the receipt_id.

Comment: Yes, I'm using sandbox account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discussed this with paypal developer support and it seems like the transaction sale ID is the appropriate ID to record and return to the user, it is also what gets recorded in the paypal account for a credit card transaction so if a user had a support question, it is the easiest number to give to accounts to look up the transaction details.

I am not 100% sure about how to access what is called the receipt_id, but I don't think it is intended to be populated in the response to the payment endpoint. If you are to get a receipt_id at all, it will likely come from hitting the endpoint `GET /v1/payments/sale/<Transaction-Id>`

As per the api, receipt_id is defined as

> Receipt id is 16 digit number payment identification number returned for guest users to identify the payment.

I think "guest users" may have a specific meaning that is not relevant to just any transaction but I'm not positive on this.

I would recommend playing around with this [endpoint](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#sale-transactions) after you get the transaction ID from the [payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment) endpoint. The id located in the json returned from the payments endpoint at payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id seemed to be the appropriate ID to record for a simple credit card transaction where I wanted to return a reference number to the client and to store for looking up the transaction at a later date.

I also was able to use that ID to interrogate the sale endpoint mentioned above for more information, but I never was able to get receipt_id to populate for a sandbox operation.

Hope this helps, I find some of the documentation to be lacking for the REST api.

```
"transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "tax": "0.03",
          "shipping": "0.03"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "4RR959492F879224U",
            "create_time": "2013-01-31T04:12:02Z",
            "update_time": "2013-01-31T04:12:04Z",
```